# Force Spring RestTemplate to ignore response's content type headers

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I'm trying to make a GET request to a server that I don't control, and which is returning an invalid value in the `Content-Type` header: "Application/json; charset=".

When I try to do a GET call, Spring throws a InvalidMimeTypeException when trying to parse this value because it rightly expects that there should be an actual charset following that = sign.

```
restTemplate.getForObject(new URI(DATASOURCE), String.class); // throws InvalidMimeTypeException when attempting to parse response
```

Is it possible to configure RestTemplate to ignore whatever content-type headers are returned by in the response? I have no control over the server I'm querying. (Spring-Boot 2.2.0.RELEASE.)

```
org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "Application/json; charset=": 'value' must not be empty
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:574) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:966) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.getContentType(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:135) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:744) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:717) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:336) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 1):

You implement a custom [HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-message-converters). Here an [example](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/custom-http-message-converter.html). I guess that you can reuse the JSON converter and register the custom content type.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answer latency, I'm answering so when one searches a solution for related problem, it could be a reference.

In addition to converter answer, you should extend a [ResponseExtractor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpMessageConverterExtractor.html) with HttpMessageConverter and override `getContentType` there, because RestTemplate `execute` method firstly checks content type of response and if it cannot be parsed, then also throws exception there. So both Converter and Extractor should exist.